# Java 120 bits data conversion into 32 bits

Tags: java, compression

Is there any way to convert my 120 bits of data into 32 bits, and after get back my 120 bit data from these 32 bits?

Comment: If your goal is to save the same information from 120 into 32, this is not possible. Can you please qive more information about your problem?

Comment: It is called [compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression), and it depends on the repetitions in your data how much you can shrink it.

Comment: actually i have two ips(32 bit each), two port numbers(16 bit each) and a timestamp(24 bits) which sum upto 120 bits and i wanted it to represented in 32 bits

Comment: That sounds like wanting to put the interweb on a floppy disk. Maybe you should tell us *why* you need so much information into such a small number of bits.

Answer (score 2):

It's called lossless compression and you should definitely read a [tutorial](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/Programming/compression/) about it.

With that said, the compression you can do on any piece of data is highly dependent on the redundancy of information within the data.  So you may be able to get it down to 32 bits, but there's no guarantees.

Comment: Actually i have two ips(32 bit each), two port numbers(16 bit each) and a timestamp(24 bits) which sum upto 120 bits and i wanted it to represented in 32 bits

Answer (score 1):

There is a mathematical proof that such a transformation is not possible "always", it's called the pigeon-hole principle.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pigeonhole_principle

Basically, if you could compress *any* sequence of 120 bits into 32 bits, you could recursively compress the whole web into 32 bits.

Now, it doesn't mean this is never possible : you can certainly compress some 120 bits sequences into 32 bits provided you know in advance some properties of the sequence to compress.

For example, the IPs could be part of a list, instead of being "any" possible value. The index in the list will cost less than 32 bits. Same for Port Number, it may not be completely random, and you could reduce the choice into a list of predefined numbers. If only 4 ports are possible, you will need only 2 bits (instead of 16).

For the timestamp, this is a lot more difficult. It depends on the precision of the measurement.
One possibility would be to use a "delta" value (as a +N added to a known "base"). 
The number of bits you can use for the timestamp depends on how many bits were already used by the previous fields.

So it *may* be possible to compress it into 32 bits, but there's no guarantee. It depends a lot on the variety of situations you have to take into consideration.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to compress *every* 120-bit data into 32-bit data and decompress back to the original.  However, you can only  compress *some* of them losslessly.